# How to reverse order of lines in a div while keeping the style, order of words, etc

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to reverse my line order while keeping the style of words and the order I created.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="mytext"">
    Buy - 3 Potatoes $6.25
    Sold - 3 Napkins $7.12
    Buy - 5  Fries $11.62
    Sold - 7 Potatoes $14.32
</textarea>

<div id = "myresult"></div>
```

As you can see I did the order of words and style the words I just need to reverse the lines now.
I'm working on notepad++ and still pretty new to Javascript.

**Script:**

```
  var mytext = document.getElementById('mytext');
  var result = document.getElementById('myresult');
        var lines = mytext.value.split('<br>');
        result.innerHTML = '';
        for(let i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        var line = lines[i];
        var list = [];
        list.unshift(line);
        list.unshift("<br>");
        var word = line.split(' ');
        var n1 = line.match(/[0-9]+/g);
        var n2 = line.match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g);
        var check = line.match(/Buy/);
        var check2 = line.match(/Sell/);
if(check) {  
        result.innerHTML += "<span style='color:green;'>" + word[0] + "</span>" + ' ' +  word[2] + ' ' + word[3] + ' total:$' + (n1[0]*[n2]).toFixed(2) + "<br>";
        }
     else if(check2) {  
        result.innerHTML += "<span style='color:blue;'>" + word[0] + "</span>" + ' ' +  word[2] + ' ' + word[3] + ' total: $' + (n1[0]*[n2]).toFixed(2) + "<br>";
        }
    else { 
        result.innerHTMl + " ";
    }

}
```

As you can see I already style the colors and fix the order. I just need to reverse the line and display it in innerHTML.

My idea was to make a array[], and then for every line in the for loop try to unshift the line and br but everytime it give errors sometimes it gives me a bunch of commas, and one time it it displays no colors or give me a bunch of random words.

Result should look like what is after the snippet run. This is what I want innerHTMl after the code is run. The code has to display innerHTMl inside the div please.

```html
<div id="result">
  <span style='color:blue;'>Sold</span> 7 Potatoes total: $100.24<br>
  <span style='color:green;'>Buy</span> 5 Fries total: $58.1<br>
  <span style='color:blue;'>Sold</span> 3 Napkins total: $21.36<br>
  <span style='color:green;'>Buy</span> 3 Potatoes total: $18.75<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok.... but javascript has a `reverse()` prototype function already for arrays... In case you didnt know. ... I suppose *I want to reverse my line order while keeping the style of words and the order I created.* needs more explanantion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In continuation of my comment above, you could use js `reverse()` before anything else on creating new elements.

E.g.

```
var lines = mytext.value.split("\n").reverse();
```

Comment: The `textarea` doesn't have any `br` elements within it.

Comment: Thanks I saw the reverse function for strings on W3Schools so I tried result.reverse(); and then list[].reverse() and then I did result.innerHTML.reverse() until your answer

Comment: @Elliot in js you can just keep chaining new functions to the result. So since `split()` returns an array you can chain `reverse()` to it since that `split()`'s return is an array. Depends on how the internals work but the prototypes work well.